# Node JS - Discord js - Chat logging with winston to quick-db

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, quick.db

So, I want to add a chat logging system with sql with quick-db, currently I have this as a temporary fix, but its just to ugly how it logs.

```
yumi.on('ready', () => {
 winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'yumi.log', level: 'info' });
});

yumi.on('message', msg => {
  winston.log('info', msg.guild + ' - ' + msg.channel.name + ' - ' + "@ " + msg.author.username + '#' + msg.author.disscriminator + msg.author + ' | ' + msg.content)
});
```

How would I go about storing username with client id into sqlite or by using this fancy tool called [quick.db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db)

any idea or how to start by doing this?